# How do I delete a ChartSheet in Excel 2010 using an Application level VSTO addin?

Tags: excel, vsto

I have an application level add-in for Excel 2010.  I need the ability to delete worksheets as well as chart sheets from a workbook.  Deleting the worksheets is not a problem, using the following code:

```
Worksheet wsDel = (Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[WorksheetName];
wsDel.Delete();
```

Deleting chart sheets, however, is a problem as I cannot cast them to a 'ChartSheet' object.  I'm trying the following code:

```
object TheObject = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
for (int i = 1; i <= Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Count; i++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("The type is '{0}'", Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Charts[i]);
                object TempObject = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Charts[i];

                if (TheObject == TempObject)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Eureka!");
                }
            }
```

'TempObject' is of type '__ComObject'.  Any idea to what I can cast it so I can delete it at the Debug.WriteLine("Eureka") line?

Regards,
J

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd suggest breaking the chain of calls and declare each property or method call on a separate line of code. Thus, you will be able to release each underlying COM object instantly. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Excel object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. You can read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945(v=office.12).aspx) article in MSDN. It is related to Outlook, but the same principles can be applied to all Office applications.

You can use the IDispatch and ITypeInfo interfaces to get the underlying type:

1. Cast the object to the IDispatch type.
2. Get the ITypeInfo interface via IDispatch.GetTypeInfo().
3. Get the type name using ITypeInfo.GetDocumentation().

   ```
   public static string GetTypeName(object comObj)
   {

       if (comObj == null)
           return String.Empty;

       if (!Marshal.IsComObject(comObj))
           //The specified object is not a COM object
           return String.Empty;

       IDispatch dispatch = comObj as IDispatch;
       if (dispatch == null)
           //The specified COM object doesn't support getting type information
           return String.Empty;

       ComTypes.ITypeInfo typeInfo = null;
       try
       {
           try
           {
               // obtain the ITypeInfo interface from the object
               dispatch.GetTypeInfo(0, 0, out typeInfo);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               //Cannot get the ITypeInfo interface for the specified COM object
               return String.Empty;
           }

           string typeName = "";
           string documentation, helpFile;
           int helpContext = -1;

           try
           {
               //retrieves the documentation string for the specified type description 
               typeInfo.GetDocumentation(-1, out typeName, out documentation,
                   out helpContext, out helpFile);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               // Cannot extract ITypeInfo information
               return String.Empty;
           }
           return typeName;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           // Unexpected error
           return String.Empty;
       }
       finally
       {
           if (typeInfo != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(typeInfo);
       }
   }
   ```

See [HowTo: get the actual type name behind System.__ComObject with Visual C# or VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/12/20/type-name-system-comobject/) for more information.